# Having trouble compiling boost filesystem's tutorial file

Tags: c++, boost, linker, clang, homebrew

I'm attempting to compile [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/example/tut3.cpp) tutorial file from boost::filesystem.

I'm using this command:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ tut3.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::path::path<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>, void>::type*) in tut3-FljaLL.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using the clang included in Mountain Lion, and boost is installed with `brew install --with-mpi --use-clang`.  (mpich2 is also installed with `--use-clang`).

The verbose linker output:

```
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.1.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name tut3.cpp -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 133.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/nb/qkspw0z92f506gbjq9gb505r0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/spott/Documents/Code/ebss/bin -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 272 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/nb/qkspw0z92f506gbjq9gb505r0000gn/T/tut3-9Q4qRh.o -x c++ tut3.cpp
clang -cc1 version 4.0 based upon LLVM 3.1svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o a.out -L/usr/local/lib/ /var/folders/nb/qkspw0z92f506gbjq9gb505r0000gn/T/tut3-9Q4qRh.o -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt -lc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&)", referenced from:
  boost::filesystem::path::path<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>, void>::type*) in tut3-9Q4qRh.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm honestly not sure what the problem is, any ideas?

Comment: have you verified that the library which you are attempting to link against actually exists in /usr/local/lib?

Comment: also, post verbose linker output, it may help.

Comment: I'll post the verbose linker output when I get home, however I can say for sure that the libraries do exist at that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got the same issue for using filesystem on MacOS.

Could not go through without compiling boost with the following options:

/b2 --build-dir=../boost_libs toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" stage --with-filesystem

This post was useful by the way: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404500/compile-boost-1-52-c11-clang-mac-10-8-2-cannot-find-cstddef).

Comment: Do you know the flags to pass to homebrew's 'brew' command to enable these compilation flags? Or do I have to edit boost.rb manually?