# Compile boost C++11 clang mac cannot find cstddef

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, clang

I cannot compile boost with clang 3.1 on Mac os x 10.8.2.

This is what I did:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

I also tried without chrono, test, wave and signals.
I tried a user-config.jam with

```
using clang-darwin
```

This is the error I have for almost every file:

```
/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18:12: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
```

It is kind of similar to [How to compile/link Boost with clang++/libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486077/how-to-compile-link-boost-with-clang-libc)

Thank you :-)

Update:
I do have the latest Xcode 4.5.2 with the command line tools installed.

Here is part of the console output:

```
Kikohs:trunk kikohs$ ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
Performing configuration checks

- 32-bit                   : no
- 64-bit                   : yes
- x86                      : yes
- has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - gcc visibility           : yes
    - long double support      : no
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
```

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.

```
- iconv (libc)             : no
- iconv (separate)         : yes
- icu                      : no
- icu (lib64)              : no
```

Component configuration:

```
- atomic                   : building
- chrono                   : building
- context                  : building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : building
- filesystem               : building
- graph                    : building
- graph_parallel           : building
- iostreams                : building
- locale                   : building
- math                     : building
- mpi                      : building
- program_options          : building
- python                   : building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : building
- serialization            : building
- signals                  : building
- system                   : building
- test                     : building
- thread                   : building
- timer                    : building
- wave                     : building

...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 8672 targets...
...updating 1127 targets...
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/atomic
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/atomic/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug
clang-darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/lockpool.o
In file included from libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp:1:
./boost/atomic.hpp:10:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#include <cstddef>
     ^
1 error generated.

"clang++" -x c++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_SOURCE -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/debug/lockpool.o" "libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp"
```

Comment: I've corrected your title, changing `cstddef.h` to `cstddef`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem after many hours.

Homebrew was messing with my path and for some reason my clang could not find the libc++ headers.

There is a bug is boost 1.52.

See [Boost numeric limits bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7671)

I had to edit the file :

```
boost/config/stdlib/libcpp.hpp
```

and patch it:

```
#if _LIBCPP_VERSION < 1002 
#   define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NUMERIC_LIMITS 
#endif
```

Now boost is building properly ...

Comment: Homebrew now has the option to build boost with c++11, boost is patched by homebrew :-).

Comment: Just a note, I don't think there's a way to do this with travis-ci if you're building boost alongside your project. If anyone finds a way, let me know, but I don't think there's a way due to how outdated travis-ci's clang is.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you forgot to install the libc++ headers alongside clang.

If you don't want to mess with installing the headers, try the version of clang distributed by Apple as part of the Command Line Tools package; it's been through more testing, and it's already set up properly.

Answer (score -3):

For Ubuntu 16.04, I'm able to build boost with c++11 using gcc:

cd /home/user/install/boost/boost_1_54/

./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc

./b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags="-std=c++11 -I/usr/include/c++/5/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/"

mkdir ../2

./b2 install --prefix=../2/

The command for building my program:

g++ -std=c++11 -O2 fprint.cpp -o fprint -I/home/user/install/boost/2/include/ -L/home/user/install/boost/2/lib/ -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options

Before that the command was:

g++ -std=c++11 fprint.cpp -o fprint -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options

, but this old command (that worked before well with older OS and boost/etc) doesn't work anymore saying errors
"
undefined reference to boost::re_detail_106501
"
(said by /tmp/cc0Zn8lo.o: In function `bool boost::regex_search...)

((also if I don't use "-I/usr/include/c++/5/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/" for ./b2, then the error is "cannot find cstddef" during building boost, so exactly the same like the subject of this ticket))