# Boost.Wave 1.52 does not build using clang++ on Darwin

Tags: boost, clang, darwin, clang++

I've applied [Compile boost C++11 clang mac cannot find cstddef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404500/compile-boost-1-52-c11-clang-mac-10-8-2-cannot-find-cstddef)
and invoked build as follows
`./b2 variant=debug,release --layout=versioned toolset=clang cxxflags="-fPIC -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" threading=multi link=shared --stagedir=stage_darwin_intel_shared_mt stage`

And everything builds, except for a log of warnings and except for Boost.Wave fails:
http://pastebin.com/ZHkmTWaq

P.S. Static flavor of boost builds Wave fine.

Comment: A glance at your output suggests that wave needs to link against boost_system. Let's see what happens when I try to build.

Comment: This may have been fixed already; building against boost's trunk succeeded (for me). You might want to try the 1.53.0 beta release available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.53.0.beta.1/ to see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation that beta works. I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct compilation

```
./b2 variant=debug,release --layout=versioned toolset=clang cxxflags="-fPIC -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" linkflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" threading=multi link=shared --stagedir=stage_darwin_intel_shared_mt stage
```